# Getting error code 2869 while installing an upgraded version of the same application

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, setuptools, setup-deployment, error-code

I have a C#.NET application having some version 1.0.0.1. I did some modifications to my application & want to release it with an upgraded version 1.0.0.2.

If the older version 1.0.0.1 is already installed in client's system & if client tries to install the newer version 1.0.0.2, then it is throwing the followin error message

> Installer has encountered an
>   unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem
>   with this package. The error code is
>   2869.

Initially after changing the version no:, I had also changed the productCode of the new version.  But did not modify the upgrage code in the set up project.

Can any one kindly let me know how to fix this error 2869.. 
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Error 2869 is about an error dialog "The dialog [2] has the error style bit set, but is not an error dialog"; it is not likely to be the real error. Inspect a verbose log (/l*v setup.log) and look for what action gives return value 3.

Comment: I am totally new 2 this. Kindly let me know, what does this dialog[2], mean. ? I didnt understand your answer. Kindly explain.  How to fix this issue.

Comment: 2869 is not the root cause of this issue. This is a well known bogus error from Visual Studio setup projects. The install has already failed and it's going to show you an error, but it doesn't like the layout of the dialog. The actual root cause will be earlier in the log.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is your product version. Windows Installer ignores the fourth version field, so you should use only the first three fields (for example 1.0.0 and 1.0.1).

After fixing the version, try creating an installation log (/L*V parameter for msiexec.exe) to see what happens. Usually error 2869 is shown when a .NET installer class action encounters an exception or has invalid parameters (it's rarely related to a dialog).

Comment: I created the verbose log file. It has so many fields. Can You kindly let me know, analyze this log file in order to fix my error.

Comment: Post is somewhere or provide a link to it so we can take a look.